# React router guard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, frontend

I'm new to react JS and learning react router. I recently got stuck on what I'm doing. What I'm trying to do is a route should not be accessible when user is not or is authenticated.

- When not authenticated user should only be able to access **/home** and **/login**
- When authenticated they can only access **/profile**, **/settings** and not be able to access the other routes either using browser back button or change browser URL.

What is happening is I'm still able to access all the routes even if I change **isAuthenticated** returned value.

I'm using React 18.2.0 and React Router 6.

Below are my codes

**Main.tsx**

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from '@modules/home/views'
import LoginPage from '@modules/login/views'
import ProfilePage from '@modules/profile/views'
import SettingsPage from '@modules/Settings/views'
import { PublicRoutes, ProtectedRoutes } from 'src/middleware/AppRoutes'

const AppMain = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
          <Route path="/settings" element={<SettingsPage />} />
        </Route>
        
        <Route element={<PublicRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </main>
  )
}

export default AppMain
```

**RouteGuard.tsx**

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  return false
}

export const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  return !isAuthenticated()
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location }} replace />
}

export const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  return isAuthenticated()
    ? <Navigate to='/profile' state={{ from: location }} replace />
    : <Outlet />
}
```

Comment: this might help....https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth#preview

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the auth condition and the ternary.

If the user is authenticated ***and*** accessing a protected route you should render the `Outlet`, otherwise render the redirect to `"/login"`.

If the user is authenticated ***and*** accessing a public route you should render the redirect to `"/profile"`, otherwise render the `Outlet`.

Example:

```
const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return isAuthenticated() ? (
    <Navigate to="/profile" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  ) : (
    <Outlet />
  );
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return isAuthenticated() ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-guard]

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, I've tried your solution,but now I'm getting this on my console multiple times. " Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render. " is this related to react router?

Comment: @PenAndPapers Did you catch that the redirect paths also needed to be swapped? If that isn't the issue can you fork the codesandbox I provided and add in more of your code to see if you can reproduce it there, and if so, share the link to your fork so we can inspect and debug it live?

Comment: I only catch that when I return a false. But when true I can still access all routes which should not be

Comment: @PenAndPapers I can't reproduce that behavior with the code in the sandbox I provided. I just added links to make testing easier. When `isAuthenticated` returns false, only the public routes are accessible, and when it returns true, the private routes are accessible. Can you create a sandbox demo for us to inspect?